# Change docker container’s log PATH

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

Team:
All my container logs are under /var/log/containers..

Where in kubelet or docker config can I specify this path such that logs are instead created under new path?
Ex : /shared ? Instead of /var/log

Comment: I can't find anything either. It's also the case with containerd runtime. Good point. If you can't figure it out, one way to go about this might be to mount-bind your /var/log/containers from your arbitrary logs directory - see https://serverfault.com/a/613184/293779

Comment: @AhmFM could you specify why you want the change the log path?

Comment: Because I don’t like users writing to root directly. So I created a slice partition from root and want container logs to be written there instead.

Comment: You might circumvent this by using syslog, or other logging facility if you can configure the host and set up the log path there.

Answer (score 1):

I got a work around to this case. basically, My root volume is 100GB and I created a separate partition out of it as 70GB and I set it to a new device sda3 and mounted it to /var/lib.

now, all docker container logs are written in same path but in backend they are mounted to a different drive. with this setup, even if there is disk pressure, the node does not become unavailable.

so my drive now looks liek below

```
sda1
sda2 / 30GB
sda3 /var/lib 70GB.  << new device
```